# CSS - Tab Style Where The Active Button Is The Only Thing Without a Line Underneath

Tags: html, css, angular

So, I'm trying to find how to style a set of tabs to look similar to [this, where there's a line underneath the inactive buttons while the active button is missing that underline.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGKqg.png)

My first thought would be to use the border style to just have anything not active have a border-bottom and an active button to have a border everywhere except the bottom. However, that doesn't cause the entire area to have the underline.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, I essentially have buttons that I use as tabs to switch between pieces of content, displaying one or the other. What I want is to style the tab and tab buttons so that it looks similar to the image I provided. The only issue I have currently is trying to get the bottom border to disappear on the original div under the active button.

Here's my current code for reference:

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
    <button [ngClass]="memberTabClass" (click)="changeTab(0)">Members</button>
    <button [ngClass]="eventTabClass" (click)="changeTab(1)">Events</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    height: 4vh;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    width: 97%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.tab button {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tab button.active {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    color: rgb(72, 115, 255);
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

TS:

```
//default Values for classes and styles
  activeTabClass: string = "active";
  defaultTabClass: string = "";
  displayOn: string = "block";
  displayOff: string = "none";

  //Starting values for tabs
  memberTabClass = this.activeTabClass;
  eventTabClass = this.defaultTabClass;
  currentTab = 0;
  memberDisplay = this.displayOn;
  eventDisplay = this.displayOff;

  changeTab(tab: number){
    if(tab==0 && tab!=this.currentTab){
      this.memberTabClass=this.activeTabClass;
      this.eventTabClass=this.defaultTabClass;
      this.currentTab=0;
      this.memberDisplay=this.displayOn;
      this.eventDisplay=this.displayOff;
    }
    else if(tab==1 && tab!=this.currentTab){
      this.memberTabClass=this.defaultTabClass;
      this.eventTabClass=this.activeTabClass;
      this.currentTab=1;
      this.memberDisplay=this.displayOff;
      this.eventDisplay=this.displayOn;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet and also your question is hard to understand. Please edit it with the code

Comment: Sure, just updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important parts are:

- Add content with `::after` to the `div` around all the tabs. The content need to have a `border-bottom` and a `position` of `absolute` and his parent need to be `relative`. Move the added content to the bottom.
- Add a `border-bottom` to the active tab with the color that blend with the style of you tab. The active tab need a z-index to be over the added content.
- Add a transparent `border` to all the tabs, individually, because the the tabs will shift when you add javascript to change the active tab. They will shift because they don't have a border before adding one to the active tab. If you add a transparent border, they won't shift because they already have the transparent border.

```css
#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.tabs{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    
}

.tab{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 20px;
    
}
.tabs::after{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

div.active{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <div class="tabs">
          <div class="tab tab-1">Tab 1</div>
          <div class="tab tab-2 active">Tab 2</div>
          <div class="tab tab-3">Tab 3</div>
      </div>
</div>
```